# How to use MSAL with React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I feel I might be close, but I can't get the [msal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) library to work with react.

After logging in via Microsoft I get redirected to my callback but with the code in the URL, e.g.

`http://localhost:3000/authcallback#code=0.AQsAuJTIrioCF0ambVF28BQibk37J9vZQ05FkNq4OB...etc`

The `interaction.status` key in local storage is stuck on `interaction_in_progress`

I'm using the redirect flow and I suspect there is something wrong with how I'm registering the required callback.

Here is my wrapper class `AuthService.ts`

```js
export class AuthService {
    msalClient: PublicClientApplication;
    loginRequest: RedirectRequest;
    account: AccountInfo | null;

    constructor(configuration: Configuration, loginScope: string) {
        this.msalClient = new PublicClientApplication(configuration);
        this.loginRequest = {
            scopes: [loginScope, "openid", "profile"],
        };
        this.account = null;
    }

    loadAuthModule(): void {
        this.msalClient
            .handleRedirectPromise()
            .then((resp: AuthenticationResult | null) => {
                if (resp) {
                    this.handleResponse(resp);
                }
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }

    handleResponse(response: AuthenticationResult) {
        if (response !== null) {
            store.dispatch(signIn(response.account));
        }
    }

    signIn(): void {
        this.msalClient.loginRedirect(this.loginRequest);
    }

    signOut(): void {
        this.msalClient.logout();
    }

    async getIdentity(): Promise<AuthenticationResult | null> {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Here is my config wrapper class

```js
export class AuthConfig {
    configuration: Configuration;
    loginScope: string;

    constructor(clientId: string, authority: string, redirectUrl: string, loginScope: string) {
        this.loginScope = loginScope;
        this.configuration = {
            auth: {
                clientId: clientId,
                authority: authority,
                redirectUri: redirectUrl,
                navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
            },
            system: {
                loggerOptions: {
                    loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
                        if (containsPii) {
                            return;
                        }
                        switch (level) {
                            case LogLevel.Error:
                                console.error(message);
                                return;
                            case LogLevel.Info:
                                console.info(message);
                                return;
                            case LogLevel.Verbose:
                                console.debug(message);
                                return;
                            case LogLevel.Warning:
                                console.warn(message);
                                return;
                        }
                    },
                },
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Then in my login page which is the first page on the site...

```
export let authService = {} as AuthService;

const LoginPage: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({}) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const config = new AuthConfig(
            (window as any).ENV.CLIENT_ID,
            (window as any).ENV.AUTHORITY,
            (window as any).ENV.REDIRECT_URL,
            (window as any).ENV.LOGIN_SCOPE
        );

        authService = new AuthService(config.configuration, config.loginScope);  
        authService.loadAuthModule();    
    }, [])

    const signIn = () => {
        authService.signIn();
    };

    return (    
        <Button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign In</Button>          
    );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

My config details are correct. I assume I wouldn't get as far as I can without them being correct.

Where am I going wrong here?

Every example I have seen has hard coded values for the config but this doesn't seem very secure, hence attempting to inject them from my `config.js` file. I'm open to suggestions on how to do this whilst maintaining a globally accessible msal instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released the first alpha for our official Msal React wrapper, where you can see our approach: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/releases/tag/msal-react-v1.0.0-alpha.0

Comment: I was looking for something production ready, but I'll have a look at the code to get some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @Konzy262 facing same issue, loginPopUp worked for me , but loginRedirect is giving me undefined results. i'm also using msal library. is the alpha version good to use?

Comment: @Wolverine With the code above, when using hard coded config data it mostly worked for me. In the wrapper class I would do `const authService = new AuthService()`, then `export default authService`. I would then use this 'global' instance anywhere in React. With custom config settings it worked for me after I moved the auth service instance creation and callback registration to the `index.tsx` file. The only downside is the first time your app is accessed in the browser, the callback is run.

Comment: @Wolverine This doesn't affect the usability and the login still worked fine. Just means you get a few additional logging statements initially. It's all a little hacky though and I'm sure the official library will be better, once released.

Comment: yeah, i integrated the official library , integration went smoother :) because of the new context api

Answer (score 0):

I can definitely see an argument about maintainability for pushing this out to config, but you should not consider it a security measure. If it's available to client-side javascript, it's available for inspection in dev tools.